# Adding multiple users to groups in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a CSV file which has a list of users and groups they belong to. I am trying to script the same to automate it using PowerShell but seem to be facing an error. When I try to debug it I see that for some reason the user name value is being blank.

Any assistance will be helpful.

```
$Users = import-csv -Path "C:\Scripts\listofusers.csv" 

foreach-Object ($User in $Users)
{
    $SAM = $User.'SAM'
    $group = $User.'Group'

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members "$SAM"
}
```

Test Data

```
Group                  SAM

IT                     Test1   
Engineering            Test3
```

Comment: Can't you just throw that bad boy in a For Each loop and call it a day?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
foreach-Object ($User in $Users)
```

to:

```
foreach ($User in $Users)
```

The
     `foreach`  statement iterates over a collection of objects whereas the     `foreach-object` is used in a pipeline

Hence try the following:

```
$Users = import-csv -Path "C:\Scripts\listofusers.csv" 
foreach ($User in $Users) { 
$SAM = $User.'SAM' 
$group = $User.'Group' 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members "$SAM" 
}
```

Comment: I have amended the answer to include the full code - try this.  To confirm the heading in you csv is still "group" and "sam"?

Comment: No Still no difference. I am going to make the group as constant and see if it changes post which will debug why the loop is not working.

Comment: I have tried the code here and I know it works.  I think the problem is with your csv file.  Try to recreate your csv using excel but save it as a csv and try again (ensuring the headings remain the same i.e. sam and group)

Comment: Ya i was thinking about that and had the same issue. I am seeing if I should upload it as a text instead of csv, will keep you posted if that changes anything. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If data is as you wrote, then you need to define delimiter while importing data from CSV. By default, delimiter is comma, so its not fitting your data. Just use

```
 $Users = import-csv -Path 'C:\Scripts\listofusers.csv' -Delimiter ' '
```

If that is not a space, but tab, then use `t (that's backtick in front of t).

Comment: Even after defining the type of delimiter it was not accepting. If I keep the group name constant and add multiple users it acknowledges it but i am not able to automate it to pick up the different groups and user names at the same time.